# Random re-sampling without any overlaps

Tags: python, r, awk, sed

I have a table with 3000 rows and 50,000 columns. From this data I want to make 5 datasets that contain 10% of the original data without any overlaps (In this case 10% of 3000=300). Also i want to have a remove the resampled dataset from the original one. Example

```
1.Original data (O)
a. Randomly resampled dataset1 (RD1)
b. Randomly resampled dataset2 (RD2)
c. Randomly resampled dataset3 (RD3)
d. Randomly resampled dataset4 (RD4)
e. Randomly resampled dataset5 (RD5)
2. remove RD from O 
a. O - RD1 = New dataset1
b. O - RD2 = New dataset2
c. O - RD3 = New dataset3
d. O - RD4 = New dataset4
e. O - RD5 = New dataset5
```

I tried random re-sampling like below in R

```
original=read.table("table1.txt", header=F)
RD1=original[sample(nrow(original), replace=F, size=0.1*nrow(original)), ]
```

But it has overlaps. How do I make non overlapping sets? and how do i remove RDs from original set to make new data sets? Any awk, sed , python or R solution?

Comment: Maybe you should try this `RD1=original[sample(1:nrow(original), replace=F, size=0.1*nrow(original)), ]`

Comment: [`modelr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/modelr) makes this really simple.

Comment: Or make a list of indices with something like `split(sample(20), seq(20/5))` and subset with `lapply` (with negative indexing to get the rest of the set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just shuffle the lines, or shuffle an array of indices to the array containing the lines if you don't want to change the original data, and then do whatever it is you want to do with the first 5 sets of 300 lines and delete them from what's left.

For example using input of 30 lines (the numbers 1->30) instead of 3000:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function shuf(array,    i, j, t) {
    # Shuffles an array indexed by numbers from 1 to its length
    # Copied from https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#AWK
    for (i=length(array); i > 1; i--) {
        # j = random integer from 1 to i
        j = int(i * rand()) + 1

        # swap array[i], array[j]
        t = array[i]
        array[i] = array[j]
        array[j] = t
    }
}

{ arr[NR] = $0 }

END {
    srand()
    shuf(arr)
    numBlocks = 5
    pct10 = length(arr) * 0.1
    for (i=1; i<=numBlocks; i++) {
        print "------- Block", i
        for (j=1; j<=pct10; j++) {
            print ++c, arr[c]
            delete arr[c]
        }
    }
    print "\n------- Remaining"
    for (i in arr) {
        print i, arr[i]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ seq 30 | awk -f tst.awk
------- Block 1
1 24
2 27
3 28
------- Block 2
4 11
5 16
6 19
------- Block 3
7 2
8 5
9 25
------- Block 4
10 18
11 22
12 15
------- Block 5
13 20
14 10
15 14

------- Remaining
16 12
17 17
18 1
19 8
20 23
21 21
22 9
23 30
24 7
25 29
26 6
27 26
28 13
29 3
30 4
```

and again to show that the output is random:

```
$ seq 30 | awk -f tst.awk
------- Block 1
1 17
2 15
3 22
------- Block 2
4 19
5 1
6 13
------- Block 3
7 7
8 10
9 28
------- Block 4
10 5
11 2
12 8
------- Block 5
13 16
14 11
15 30

------- Remaining
16 14
17 18
18 26
19 4
20 29
21 12
22 21
23 27
24 3
25 24
26 6
27 9
28 23
29 20
30 25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Reproducible data    
data <- mtcars
n <- nrow(data)
K <- 5
# Get indices for splitting
ind <- integer(n)
new <- rep(1:K, each = 0.1 * n)
ind[sample(n, size = length(new))] <- new
# Split data
split(data, ind)
```